# Does Android restore Intent extras when resuming Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

In the Android Activity lifecycle, when Activity.onCreate() is called after resuming (IE. not when activity created initially or in response to screen rotation) would this code return a valid (non-null) Bundle?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    // is b == null? (when activity is resumed)
}
```

I am trying to reproduce a problem that occurs when the application has not been used for a long period - when the user returns, the application crashes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> okay, so when Android kills my app and the user navigates back -
>   onCreate() is fired with a >new< Activity, and the original Intent
>   along with it's associated Extras is gone; or do the Extras get
>   attached to the new Intent by Android?

I was wondering the same thing and tested this quickly in my application.

It turns out intent extras are available when an activity is re-created after your application got killed.

Comment: Thank you for answering this -- it is a more concise explanation of what people seem to be wanting to know when they come here. I would delete mine if I could so people would stop commenting on it and instead see yours.

Answer (score 2):

I would put that code in onResume() so it will be available when returning to the foreground.